# Algorithm for finding irreducible polynomials in finite field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, algorithms, extension-field

Let $K(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)/K$ be a finite field extension and suppose we know ${\rm irr}(\alpha_1,K),\ldots,{\rm irr}(\alpha_n,K)\in K[x]$. My question is: given an arbitrary element $\lambda\in K(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$, is there an algorithm for finding ${\rm irr}(\lambda,K)$ with only the preceding information?

Comment: Thanks. I was studying last week and came up with this. I tried some simple cases like $a+b\sqrt{2}$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})/\mathbb{Q}$ and found ${\rm irr}(a+b\sqrt{2},\mathbb{Q})={\rm irr}(\sqrt{2},\mathbb{Q}) - 2ax + a^2 - 2(b^2 + 1)$. But what about more general cases?